# Combine multiple sources into one ComboBox list and show only uniques

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to combine two different lists into one ComboBox.list, but some of the values are identical and I don't want them to show up twice.

Unfortunately I'm not too experienced with VBA and the error messages are very generic, so I'm not sure why my attempts aren't working.

I found a code online that works well for combining the two, but when I add in the unique function it makes no difference. It combines the lists just fine, but it seems to ignore the unique function and so has a lot of duplicates.

This is the code that I've been using:

```
Sub Combo()

Set rng1 = sheet14.Range("Range_1")
     Set rng2 = sheet14.Range("Range_2")
    
     For Each cl In rng1
         If arStr = "" Then
             arStr = cl.Value
         Else
             arStr = arStr & "," & cl.Value
         End If
     Next cl
     
     For Each cl In rng2
         If arStr = "" Then
             arStr = cl.Value
         Else
             arStr = arStr & "," & cl.Value
         End If
     Next cl
  
    sheet13.SupplierCmb.List = WorksheetFunction.unique(Split(arStr, ","))

 End Sub
```

I've tested that the unique function works by using it on just one of the ranges and it works fine.

Comment: Welcome to SO. [Use a Dictionary](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/) to get exactly the output you want.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Thank you. That seemed to be exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the exact specifications for the `Unique`-function but could confirm that there is an issue with one-dimensional arrays.

I would suggest to use a dictionary to get the list - this will work also on older versions of Excel (but not on a Mac). You can simplify your code by creating a union of the ranges so that you have only one loop.

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Union(sheet14.Range("Range_1"), sheet14.Range("Range_2"))

For Each cell In rng
    dict(cell.Value) = ""
Next
sheet13.SupplierCmb.List = dict.Keys
```

Note that this is using early binding, so you need to set a reference to the Scripting runtime. If you don't want to do it, define the dictionary like this:

```
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

Comment: This works beautifully and simplied the code a lot as well. Thank you for the quick answer! :)

Answer (score 3):

You'd normally use a dictionary (as per the other answer) but since you called the worksheetfunction `UNIQUE()`, my guess is you may be able to use `VSTACK()` and `TOCOL()` too (latter in case of 2d-arrays) too. Though not available as a method in VBA, you can still evaluate the formula:

```
Sub Test()

Sheet13.SupplierCmb.List = Sheet14.Application.Evaluate("=UNIQUE(VSTACK(TOCOL(range_1, 3), TOCOL(range_2, 3)))")

End Sub
```

- `TOCOL()` - There to 'flatten' each of the two range object in case they are multi-dimensional. The 2nd parameter '3' would ensure to leave out errors or empty cells;
- `VSTACK()` - Vertically stack both flattened arrays;
- `UNIQUE()` - Pass only unique items as a 1d-array back as a list.

Comment: I went with the dictionary as that seemed to work really well, but thanks a lot for your answer as well!

Comment: @Matt, no worries. A dictionary has some definite pro's as laid out by Thomas.

Comment: Great, works as expected. Spreading your magic in VBA. But you are passing a 2D one-based single-column array since you have used (the preferable) `VSTACK` with `TOCOL`. To get a 1D array, use `HSTACK` with `TOROW` instead.