# Is Worksheetfunction for new excel functions CHOOSEROW, CHOOSECOLS accessible. I can access these functions in Sheet, but not in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is Worksheetfunction for new excel functions CHOOSEROW, CHOOSECOLS exist in any version if Excel. I can access these functions in Sheet, but not in VBA

Checked in my current version 15601.20456 (Semi-Annual version, can't upgrade to another channel due to company policy)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction

Comment: They are not yet accessible through the WorksheetFunction object though they can be called using the [Evaluate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) method. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75244116/9758194) is a small sample. Sidenote @FunThomas, MS is slacking since definitely not all methods are covered in that linked source.

Comment: Evaluate method doesn't work in my case since I need to deal with arrays stored in variables, not in worksheet. I guess I have to make my own equivalent functions to make it work.